# AWSSDK, S3 CopyObjectRequest returning NoSuchKey error for valid key

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am attempting to copy an S3 object, using a valid key but CopyObject() keeps returning "The specified key does not exist."

However, GetObject and ListObjects return the object without issue.
Here's a sample:

```
var copyReq = new CopyObjectRequest
{
    SourceBucket = bucketName,
    SourceKey = key,
    DestinationBucket = bucketName,
    DestinationKey = ("/UserImages/mynewkeyname.jpg"),
    StorageClass = S3StorageClass.StandardInfrequentAccess,
    CannedACL = Amazon.S3.S3CannedACL.PublicRead
};

s3.CopyObject(copyReq);

ListObjectsResponse listResponse = s3.ListObjects(new ListObjectsRequest
{
    BucketName = bucketName,
    MaxKeys = 1,
    Prefix = key
});

var request = new Amazon.S3.Model.GetObjectRequest()
    {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Key = key,
    };

var getResponse = s3.GetObject(request);
```

key and bucketname are defined else where, but they were pulled from other other API responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this line:

```
DestinationKey = ("/UserImages/mynewkeyname.jpg"),
```

It seems like a reasonable assumption that you have made the same error with the source as you have with the destination.

The root of a bucket is the empty string, not `/`, so S3 object keys do not begin with a leading slash.

To clarify, the object key for `https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/test.jpg` is `test.jpg` rather than `/test.jpg`.

Comment: Turns out it was like you said but worse. If its just one leading slash the SDK can figure it out. The key in my SourceKey was actually inserted by someone else and started with a double slash. I think that one is permanently stuck in there because I can't delete the double slash one through the console either.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the S3FileInfo.CopyTo, S3FileInfo.CopyToLocal or S3FileInfo.CopyFromLocal method to perfom copy it is more elegant way to do that with AWSSDK 3.1.0 C#